Cyclotomic fields without complex numbers
I'm reading a basic algebraic number theory textbook (Marcus, Number Fields). The text makes casual use of the fact that we know what various algebraic integers/numbers are, in $C$, and can do calculations with them. It seems to me, however, that at least on this basic level this usage is just some convenience. We should be able to e.g. talk about quadratic extensions as splitting fields of $x^2-m, m \in Z$, relying on the algebraic constructions of all necessary extensions, without "knowing" anything about real or complex numbers. I wonder if the entire book could be rewritten in this fashion!
But when I focus on some particular uses of $C$, I run into trouble rewriting them this way in my mind. For example, the n-th cyclotomic field is defined as $Q[e^{2{\pi}i/n}]$. In this way, it's obvious that the element being adjoined is an n-th root of unity but not an m-th root for any $m<n$, because we can just see that on the unit circle. How do I locate the same extension without using $C$? I can look into the splitting field of $x^n-1$, see $n$ different roots in it, but how do I prove that there's a primitive one among them, one that's not a root of my $x^m-1, m<n$? Do I need first to study and prove nontrivial results about factorizations of $x^n-1$?

I would be very sad if Marcus' fantastic book had been rewritten in this fashion.

You don't need to study factorizations of $x^n - 1$, and neither do you need to use an explicit description of the roots of unity. In fact, let's prove the following general statement:

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic 0 and let $E_n$ denote the roots of $f = x^n - 1$ in some algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$. Then $E_n$ is a group under multiplication and $E_n \cong \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$.

Proof: For a start, notice that $E_n$ is a group: Clearly $1 \in E_n$, $E_n$ is closed under multiplication since if $a^n - 1 = b^n - 1 = 0$ implies $(ab)^n - 1 = 1 \cdot 1 - 1 = 0$, and $(a^{-1})^n - 1 = (a^n)^{-1} - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0$ for all $a \in E_n$ so that $a^{-1} \in E_n$ as well. Therefore, $E_n$ is a finite subgroup of $\overline{K}^{\times}$, in particular it is cyclic.
All that's left to show is that $|E_n| = n$. To this end, note that if $f$ has a zero $a$ of multiplicity $m > 1$ in $\overline{K}$, i.e. $f = (x - a)^m g$ for some $g$, then the formal derivative of $f$ can be written as
$$
    f' = (x - a)^{m - 1} (mg + (x - a)g')
$$
in particular $(x - a)^{m - 1}$ is a factor of $f'$, but this is absurd: After all, $f' = n x^{n - 1}$ which has a zero of order $n - 1$ at 0 whereas $a \neq 0$, seeing as 0 is not a zero of $f$. Therefore the zeroes of $f$ are distinct and the claim follows. $\Box$

This result directly implies the claim: If $E_n \cong \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$, there is an element $a \in E_n$ of order $n$, which in particular is to say that $a^m - 1 \neq 0$ for all $m < n$.
As an exercise, I'll leave it to you to pinpoint the location where I used the fact that $K$ is of characteristic 0 and to think about what conditions are needed to make this work in positive characteristic.

Ah, wonderfully clear. Thank you. It was the cyclic nature of $E_n$ that I forgot about and didn't think of using.
